# CloudKit - Fetching 5 records with one field type... takes 3-4 seconds. why is it so slow?

Tags: swift, segue, cloudkit, ckquery

I have a recordtype - "DiningTypes".  "DiningTypes only has one field type, which is a string.  I have 5 records... and it takes 3-4 second to load a table.  How is that this is so slow?  Do I need to begin the fetching process in a previous controller to have quicker UI response times?

```
import UIKit
import CloudKit

class table1: UITableViewController {

var categories: Array<CKRecord> = []
var fetchedcategories: Array<CKRecord> = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    func fetchdiningtypes()

    {
        let container = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
        let publicDatabase = container.publicCloudDatabase
        let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)

        let query = CKQuery(recordType: "DiningTypes", predicate: predicate)


        publicDatabase.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) { (results, error) -> Void in
            if (error != nil)
            {
                print("Error" + (error?.localizedDescription)!)
            }
            else
            {
                for result in results!
                {
                    self.categories.append(result)
                }

                              }
        }

    }
    fetchdiningtypes()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return categories.count
}
   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("dining")     as! table1cell
    let restaurant: CKRecord = categories[indexPath.row]
    cell.Name.text = restaurant.valueForKey("Name") as? String

    return cell
}
}
```

Comment: I'v frequently heard the comment development is far slower than production, if your've made your code as efficient as possible, than more you can not do.

Comment: Have you seen this in any online publication?  It sounds promising.

Answer (score 1):

The default quality of service for CloudKit operations is `NSQualityOfServiceUtility`. If your application isn't in the foreground when the request runs you may see operations take longer than usual to run.

Try using `CKQueryOperation` and setting its `qualityOfService` to `NSOperationQualityOfServiceUserInitiated`.

Comment: Apologies for the deylayed response, would you happen to know of any NSO Quality of Service Initiated tutorials?